# Can the YANG module have a list inside a grouping?

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

My code is as follows.

1.

```
grouping policy-attributes {
    container qospolicies {
        list qospolicy {
            key "uuid";
            uses attrs:base-attributes;
            uses qos-policy-attributes;
            uses bandwidth-limit-attributes;
            uses dscp-marking-attributes;
        }
    }
}
```

The grouping with the list

2.

```
grouping bandwidth-limit-rules-attributes {
    list bandwidth-limit-rule{
    leaf qos-rule-id {
        type yang:uuid;
        description "The rule id of the associated rule";
    }
    leaf max-kbps {
        type uint64;
        description "The maximum KBPS value";
    }
    leaf max-burst-kbps {
        type uint64;
        description "The burst over the maximum KBPS value";
    }
    leaf policy-id {
        type yang:uuid;
        description "The policy id to which the rule is associated";
    }
    }
}
```

3.

```
grouping dscp-marking-rules-attributes {
    list dscp-marking-rule{
    leaf qos-rule-id {
        type yang:uuid;
        description "The rule id of the associated rule";
    }
    leaf dscp-mark {
        type uint8{
        range "0 | 8 | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 | 18 | 20 | 22 | 24 | 26 | 28 | 30 | 32 | 34 | 36 | 38
        | 40 | 46 | 48 | 56 ";}
        description "the value of dscp mark";
    }
    leaf policy-id {
        type yang:uuid;
        description "the policy id to which the rule is associated";
    }
    }
}
```

The grouping `bandwidth-limit-rules-attributes` has the list with leaves. Also the `bandwidth-limit-rules-attributes` is used in the grouping `policy-attributes`. I would like to know if it is valid to have the `bandwidth-limit-rules-attributes` in `policy-attributes`.

Comment: A side note: `key "uuid"` means that you must have a leaf with such name directly as a substatement of the `list` or directly in one of the groupings used by that list. I hope, that this is satisfied by some of the other groupings that you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a `list` as a substatement to a `grouping`. Here's the list of possible substatements for a `grouping` from [RFC6020](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.11.1) (YANG 1.0).

```
 +--------------+---------+-------------+
 | substatement | section | cardinality |
 +--------------+---------+-------------+
 | anyxml       | 7.10    | 0..n        |
 | choice       | 7.9     | 0..n        |
 | container    | 7.5     | 0..n        |
 | description  | 7.19.3  | 0..1        |
 | grouping     | 7.11    | 0..n        |
 | leaf         | 7.6     | 0..n        |
 | leaf-list    | 7.7     | 0..n        |
 | list         | 7.8     | 0..n        | <--
 | reference    | 7.19.4  | 0..1        |
 | status       | 7.19.2  | 0..1        |
 | typedef      | 7.3     | 0..n        |
 | uses         | 7.12    | 0..n        |
 +--------------+---------+-------------+
```

Using the grouping inside your `policy-attributes` grouping is also valid:

```
grouping policy-attributes {
    container qospolicies {
        list qospolicy {
            key uuid;
            /*
            uses attrs:base-attributes;
            uses qos-policy-attributes;
            uses bandwidth-limit-attributes;
            uses dscp-marking-attributes;
            */
            uses bandwidth-limit-rules-attributes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is is not a valid YANG `list` because of a different reason. There must be a uuid `leaf` in the grouping or in the list because of the `key uuid;` statement.

Comment: @Piotr, the definitions are valid. Groupings need not assume the way in which they are used. I would even say that this is bad practice.

Comment: I just meant that if you have a declaration of key in a list then this key must exist. The designer of the list must ensure that, not the designer of the grouping. I am not quite sure what you mean with the augmentation here. It fixes a problem inside the `policy-attributes` grouping, but why fix it from outside?

Comment: @PiotrBabij, you claimed that the `list` inside my grouping definition was invalid, which is untrue. It only becomes invalid if the `grouping` is used in a certain way. My augment does not "fix" the grouping, since it was never broken in the first place. While I agree that such a definition should be avoided, it is not invalid.

Comment: OK, there must be something I do not understand here. Are you saying that it is valid to specify a list key that refer to a non-existing leaf? This is what has been done in the `qospolicy list`.

Comment: @PiotrBabij, it is, if done within grouping scope. The leaf may exist where the grouping is used. You cannot know that until the grouping is actually used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114816/discussion-between-piotr-babij-and-predi).

Comment: I've edited the answer according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856888/878469) answer. Let's hope one of the commented `uses` provides the missing leaf.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)